# Export directory as ro and one of its subdirectories as rw

Tags: nfs

I'd like to share a folder of my Ubuntu machine read-only with other PCs in my LAN. But I'd like that one of the subdirectories of this folder is shared as read-write. I tried it with:

```
/data       ip_address(ro,async)
/data/temp  ip_address(rw,sync)
```

in my /etc/exports, but that doesn't work. This way I only get ro access to /data.

Is it possible at all to have such a setup?

Comment: Changing the order should fix the issue ( `/data/temp` first ).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.

Comment: You also have mounted /data/temp separetly?

Comment: Yes, I did. But with ```/data/temp  192.168.144.235(fsid=1,rw,subtree_check,secure)
/data       192.168.144.235(ro,fsid=0,root_squash,no_subtree_check,hide)``` it works.

Comment: I took the above from my OMV server. But there it works without separately mounting the share. OMV runs on Debian, but that shouldn't matter, should it?